# Which condition satisfies among multiple conditions in SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, multiple-conditions

This is my SQL query :

```
select * 
from table1 
where Column1 less than Condition1 
      || Column2 less than Condition2 
      || Column3 Less than Condition3
```

Now I am trying to find which condition out of above 3 conditions satisfies for a particular record in a table.

Comment: provide some sample data and expected output. So that we would be able to understand easily.

Comment: What should happen if multiple conditions are satisfiable? (Also, nobody posts a question on SO without the expectation that they'd like answers sooner rather than later)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure it's SQL SERVER? If yes, then correcting the syntax, and adding your logic.
Like Karras mentioned, you already have * in the select which was already making you sure which column was satisfying the WHERE clause, but this code may help you further.

```
SELECT *,  
  CASE 
    WHEN Column1 < Condition1
    THEN 'Column 1 satisfies'
    WHEN Column2 < Condition2
    THEN 'Column 2 satisfies'
    WHEN Column3 < Condition3
    THEN 'Column 3 satisfies'
  END as ConditionFlag
FROM table1 
WHERE Column1 < Condition1 OR Column2 < Condition2 OR Column3 < Condition3;
```

Comment: Thank you Chaos Legion. It really helped me !!

Answer (score 0):

As long as you use `*` to return the full result set, you should be able to see the values for Column1, Column2, Column3 and understand which of the conditions evaluated to true.